# Google Chrome bookmarks bar addition order

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Ctrl+D lets me quickly add a bookmark to the end of the bookmarks bar, although I'd like to add it at the beginning, so that it's immediately visible. What's the solution?

Comment: With drag and Drop on bookmark bar you can have the location of your choice, I don't think that it is possible with the shortcut. Maybe some add on will make this possible, but I have not seen one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always just drag the address from the address bar straight down onto the bookmark bar where I want it (instead of ctrl+d), in order for that to work you have to select the whole address first or click on the little icon to the left of an address in the address bar and drag it down.  You can also click+drag actual links in a website straight up to the bar where you want it.  Might be other ways to do it too, that's what I do.

I know this was a while ago but I recently found another solution to this that I really like.  A chrome extension that auto sorts bookmarks, helps you clean up duplicates, it can auto sort regardless of how you add a bookmark or where.  Sorts folders first then, webpages, deletes empty folders and other stuff.  It uses 20mb of memory which is lower then most of my extensions and you could always just turn it on only when you want it on but 20mb isn't too big a deal.

[SuperSorter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/supersorter/hjebfgojnlefhdgmomncgjglmdckngij?hl=en)